# Android Activity switching without refresh

Tags: android, android-activity, switching

I am trying to get this(switching between multiple activities) from many days...atlast i tried to do it using intent flags

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Act1.class);

if(a1)  // a1 is set true during oncreate of act1
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);

startActivity(intent) ;
```

Will this work ?? Or any other ways ?? I am not getting here. what i exactly needed

Comment: Remove this line intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT); and then run.

Comment: I wanted to bring the background activity into foreground...i wanted to switch activities between webviews...i dont wanted to load them again ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring in manifest as
 android:launchMode="singleInstance"  under the respective activty xml tag like

[this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html" ")
works